# BiFunction<> with Enum

Tags: java, java-8

I'm using BiFunction in order to send a function.

What I have now is:

```
public class Animal {
    public static String cat(
        final String field,
        final Object value
    ) {
        return "(CAT:" + field + toString(value) + ")";
    }

    public static String dog(
        final String field,
        final Object value
    ) {
        return "(DOG:" + field + toString(value) + ")";
    }
}

public String getAnimal(
    final String animalFieldName,
    final BiFunction<String, Object, String> function,
    final Object animelieldValue
) {
    return function.apply(animalFieldName, animalFieldValue);
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
new Animal("catName", Animal::cat, "catti")
```

What I want is that the BiFunction<> would be an enum,
so the signature of getAnimal() will be:

```
String getAnimal(
    final String animalFieldName,
    /* Enum that has values that are BiFunctions, */
    final Object animalFieldValue
)
```

Any suggestions? I would appreciate code examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want but does this seem to fit the bill?

```
enum Animal implements BiFunction<String, Object, String> {
    CAT,
    DOG,
    BEAR {
        @Override
        public String apply(String s, Object o) {
            return "This is a Bear!!!";
        }
    };

    @Override
    public String apply(String s, Object o) {
        return "(" + name() + ":" + s + o.toString() + ")";
    }
}

public void test() {
    for (Animal animal : Animal.values()) {
        System.out.println(animal.apply("hello", "Hello"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A variant of @OldCurmudgeon's answer, with more lambdas:

```
enum Animal implements BiFunction<String, Object, String> {
    CAT,
    DOG,
    BEAR((s, o) -> "This is a Bear!!!");

    private final BiFunction<String, Object, String> function;

    private Animal(final BiFunction<String, Object, String> function) {
        this.function = function;
    }

    private Animal() {
        super((s, o) -> "(" + name() + ":" + s + o.toString() + ")");
    }
}

public void test() {
    Animal
        .values()
        .stream(animal -> animal.apply("hello", "Hello"))
        .forEach(System.out::println)
    ;
}
```